# How to host a webpack app behind a reverse proxy on a specific path?

Tags: javascript, webpack, caddy

I have a webpack app running behind a Caddy server, and I'm trying to set it up so that the app runs on example.com/app. I believe I have Caddy properly configured to do this (using "without /app"), and it's simple enough to change my index.html to refer to main.js as app/main.js. However, all the internal references generated by webpack (such as chunks, etc) aren't aware of the setup. I've looked at the webpack proxy and publicPath options but they don't quite seem to be what I need. I'm sure this is a really common scenario but it's not obvious to me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `publicPath` is indeed the answer:

```
output: {
  publicPath: '/app/',
}
```

I was confused because when I looked at the bundled file, the urls didn't appear to have been modified. Webpack must do some other dark magic behind the scenes to make it work.